# How to get values of form in functional component with react bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, forms, bootstrap-4, ref

I find plenty of resources for this problem for class components, but how do I get the values of bootstraps FormControls inside a functional component like this? I never used refs before, so I am not quite sure, how to approach this task inside of a functional component.

```
import React from "react";
import { Modal, Button, Form, Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import Button from "../button/Button";

export default function NewEventModal(props) {

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.elements) /*How to get name value?*/
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      {...props}
      size="lg"
      aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
      centered
    >
      <Form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
              Create Event
            </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <Form.Group controlId="formGridName">
              <Form.Label>Eventname</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Input the eventname" inputRef={(ref) => { this.name = ref }}/>
            </Form.Group>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button type="submit" text="Erstellen" />
            <Button onClick={props.onHide} text="Close"/>
          </Modal.Footer>
          </Form>
      </Modal>

  );
}
```